# Compile js file with coffee file

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

Do you know if it is possible to build a js file (jquery for example) with another file that contains coffeescript? The end result is to obtain a single JS file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a build tool like Grunt.

Compile and merge coffeescript files with [grunt contrib coffee](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-coffee) and then use a build task to merge the javascript files and compiled coffeescript files into a single file: http://gruntjs.com/sample-gruntfile

You may also take a look at [grunt contrib uglify](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify)

Comment: Hi Jed ! I also use Grunt, but the main concern is first compiled Coffee Script and then concatenate all the files. The ideal would be to do it all at once ?

Comment: why does it matter? You have to compile your coffeescript in order for the javascript engine to read it anyway.

Comment: Yes indeed. I will take your advice on your first post, thank you :)